# Why doesn't scientific notation work in Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ipython

Why in Ipython does:

```
In [1]:    1E6
Out[1]: 1000000
```

work but:

```
In[2]: import numpy as np
       rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

In[3]: rng.rand([1E6])
```

produces: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

however if I type in:

```
In[4]: rng.rand(1000000)
```

It works?

Comment: `1E6` gives `1000000.0` (note the decimal point).  That is, when you use scientific notation, you always get a floating point value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that scientific can also be used to represent tiny numbers:

```
1E-3
```

so using a `float` here makes sense. If you now check the type of `1E6` you will notice

```
type(1E6)  # <class 'float'>
```

whereas

```
type(1000000)  # <class 'int'>
```

And your code complains

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

So if you explicitly cast `1E6` to an `int` it will work as expected

```
rng.rand(int(1E6))
```